# Write the computername to a text file if the name is not already in the text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a small batch file that writes the computer name to a log.txt. I need the batch file to scan the list of computernames currently in the file. If the name exist then just exit and if the name doe snot exist I need it to write it.

I have written the part to write the computer name to a file

```
Echo %computername%>>C:\log.txt
```

Now I need it to read the log and only write the computer name if it does not exist in the file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
FINDSTR "^%computername%$" < C:\log.txt >NUL || ECHO %computername%>>C:\log.txt
```

The `FINDSTR` command searches for `%computername%` in `C:\log.txt`, making sure it is not a substring of some other name (the `^` and `$` symbols around the search term, see `FINDSTR /?` for more information). If `FINDSTR` finds nothing, it raises `ERRORLEVEL`.

The `||` command delimiter means that the value of `ERRORLEVEL` should be checked before invoking the following command (`ECHO`). If `ERRORLEVEL` is raised, the command executes, otherwise it doesn't.

So, if `FINDSTR` finds nothing, the name will be added to the file.