# Need batch file to query registry key and write computer name to a log file

Tags: batch-file

I need to query the registry for HKCU\Software\test If this file exists I need to write the computer name to a log file. c:\Log.txt. I can query the registry but I have not been able to figure out how to use the if statement to add the computer name to the log file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
reg query "hkcu\software\test"
echo %COMPUTERNAME% >> c:\Log.txt
```

Comment: Show us the relevant part of your code.

Comment: reg query "hkcu\software\test" echo %COMPUTERNAME% >> c:\Log.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME% >> c:\Log.txt
```

thats all :)

Comment: reg query "hkcu\software\test" echo %COMPUTERNAME% >> c:\Log.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\test" >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 ECHO %COMPUTERNAME%>>C:\Log.txt
```

The `>nul 2>&1` will hide the output of the `REG` command. If you want to see the output, just remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same approach as in [this answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7877357/297408), only use `&&` in this case:

```
REG QUERY "whatever\you\want\to\query" >NUL && ECHO %COMPUTERNAME%>>C:\Log.txt
```

Similarly to `FINDSTR`, `REG` also sets `ERRORLEVEL` to a non-zero value if the search was unsuccessful, which allows us to use constructs with `||` and `&&` as appropriate. The command after `&&` is executed only if the search has been successful.

The above command suppresses standard output of `REG` with `>NUL`. If the search fails, the corresponding error message will still be displayed, because it is sent to the standard error device, rather than to the standard output. You can additionally suppress possible error messages by adding `2>NUL` or like in [@aphoria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038979/need-batch-file-to-query-registry-key-and-write-computer-name-to-a-log-file/8172073#8172073)'s answer.